# Unable to transfer files from Windows (NTFS) to Ubuntu (EXT4) directly

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, ntfs, ext4

I'm attempting to mount Windows (NTFS) on Ubuntu (EXT4) so that I can move files directly across. With the following command, I mounted with the correct permissions:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/OS'
```

When I try to relocate the files, however, the original copies remain on the drive and are simply copied across.

I've also tried the following (which makes no difference):

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid$(id -u) /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/
```

I've disabled fast boot. I've also tried running `ntfsfix` on the drive. No matter what happens, I am unable to relocate the files; instead, they are simply duplicated.

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you always want to see the NTFS partition when running Linux? Or is this something you only occasionally want to see? Reason I ask is because `mount` is fine for temporary assignments, while `fstab` is the place for devices that will be used regularly 

Comment: Do you have a Desktop Environment installed? Then you can use your filemanager to mount the drive and then cut and paste the files. ( Ubuntu ( EXT4 ) can see Windows ( NTFS ), but in Windows you cannot see the Ubuntu partition.)